# Usando sed con caracteres especiales

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Tengo un archivo llamada "textosed" que contiene este texto:

```
\</persistentQueues>
```

Quiero insertar las dos líneas que dejo a continuación antes del texto en mi archivo:

```
\<queue enabled=\"true\" enableHistorical=\"true\">
\</queue>
```

Este es mi código:

```
coincidencia='<\/persistentQueues>'
texto='<queue enabled=\"true\" enableHistorical=\"true\"> \n\t <\/queue>'
sed -i "#$coincidencia#i $texto" textosed
```

Al ejecutarlo no recibo ningún error pero no lleva a cabo la tarea.

He intentado escapar de los caracteres especiales con una diagonal invertida pero recibo errores.

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No queda claro cómo es exactamente tu código. Dale a [edit] y usa Control+K para darle formato, pero pon únicamente los caracteres que sí tiene, sin escapar ninguno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que escapar cuantas veces sea necesario:

```
coincidencia="<\/persistentQueues>"
texto=$'<queue enabled="true" enabledHistorical="true">\\\n<\/queue>\\\n'
sed -i -e "s/$coincidencia/$texto$coincidencia/g" textosed
```

En `coincidencia` sólo una vez el cierre de etiqueta por que va directo a sed.

En `texto` la nueva linea dos veces: una para la evaluación de texto y otra para sed.

Comment: Si no sustituyes no toma el cambio?

Comment: Muchas Gracias  a Sal